# Can I remote debug vb6 application?

Tags: debugging, vb6, remote-debugging

I wondering if I can remote debug vb6 application like in c#. I want to debug another computer across a network.

I looked at [Remote debugging in VB6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518042/remote-debugging-in-vb6) but it doesn't help me.

Comment: What do you mean? Do you mean [debugging a program on a different computer across a network](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7f5zaaa.aspx)?

Comment: Why didn't the question [Remote debugging in VB6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518042/remote-debugging-in-vb6) help you?

Comment: @MarkJ it's not for VB6, Take a look at Deanna comment about your link.

Comment: @DorCohen I know my link is for C#. You asked "can I remote debug VB6 application like in C#". I asked "What do you mean". Because I am **not sure** what **you** mean by **remote debug**. My link gives the Microsoft definition of "remote bugging" in C#: "debugging a program on a different computer across a network"? Is that what you mean? In which case [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518042/remote-debugging-in-vb6) Or do you mean "debugging a program from the exe without using the VB6 IDE". Or do you mean debugging Microsoft message queue? Or what? **What are you trying to do?**

Comment: @MarkJ I want to remote debug VB6 application down to VB6 code level.

Comment: @MarkJ Remote = from another computer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not down to VB6 code level. Normal debugging tools will help you debug at the assembly level, possibly with some code annotation but that's it.

Comment: Why in this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7f5zaaa.aspx the option of VB is marked with V?

Comment: I assume you mean the green tick? That refers to VB.NET in Visual Studio 2003+. Nothing to do with VB6.

Comment: [Yes you can debug to VB6 code level without using the VB6 IDE](http://stackoverflow.com/a/518394/15639)