# Legacy VB 6 Remote Debugging desktop application

Tags: vb6, remote-debugging

I would post what I have tried, but I have not yet found any information on how to do this. I've searched and have not come up with any answers.

I would like to be able to debug a desktop application that was written in VB 6 and is installed on a remote machine in my network from within my local VB 6 IDE.

The reason I'm using VB 6 is because the application is legacy and is being maintained (a pain).

Any help with this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: We like to stay away from the more generic [vb] tag and try to be more specific (like using [vb6] for your question).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I remote debug vb6 application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9701911/can-i-remote-debug-vb6-application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never managed to do this.

I would suggest installing VB6 on the remote machine and running the application interpreted using a remote desktop session.