# Debugging on an end-user PC?

Tags: vb6, type-mismatch

A user that works in my company has an  `Error 13 Type mismatch` in the moment that she wants to input some data in a grid.

The thing is that when she has that problem, my application only shows the error screen and nothing more (I mean it doesn't say where the error occurs).

**I want to know if there is a way that I can "see" the problem in a debug application** because I don't have the source code of my application in this computer and I don't know if the problem is because of a Windows configuration issue or why this error pops up provided that when she uses another terminal, different to the one that she normally uses, she can do her job without problems (they have the same settings in the two pcs).

I have the source code in my terminal but as say above, in my terminal the error doesn't pop up so I need to see it in her terminal.

How can I do this?

Comment: a) You install VB6 on her computer, bring the source code and debug there. b) You include of sorts of logging statements in your application, recompile, run at the terminal and then examine the log. c) If you are good at understanding compiled VB6 code, [debug remotely](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9701911/11683).

Comment: Most typically this is handled by generating logs at run time and reviewing them when unexpected events occur.

Comment: The other comments are correct. I'll add that if you see a difference in behavior from computer to computer you may likely have a dependency or installer problem, not a coding problem. I would look into any DLLs or OCX files you expect to be there (including / especially those in c:\Windows\... folders) and look for anything missing or at a wrong version.  That said, type mismatch seems to be an unlikely error to result from that kind of thing.

Comment: i have the log error that you say... " Empleado ",1222," Fecha ",#2019-05-06 13:26:41#," Sucursal ",1,"Error 13 in (Form) frmConsultaEnvios::Sub Armar_grilla (Line #: 0)",13,"13"," ","No coinciden los tipos"," ","ExpresoBrio"," ",1000013," " this is the log of the error (it says that is in the form frmConsultaEnvios and in the Sub Armar_grilla(the grid sub) but the thing that i dont know why the error ocurr... i think i will try to reinstall the ocxs or dlls of the system but i dont know if this is the cause...

Comment: In the first instance I'd watch and record over remote desktop as she entered data to see if it could be something such as different date settings on that machine.

Comment: Uhmm the date settings, the decimal and numeric settings too are correct like the other terminals but either that, the error persist... Yesterday i doesn't try reintalling all the ocx that run my application in the terminal of her... In a couple of hours i will try then i will update. Thanks for the replys... 

Another thing... GSerg proposal doesn't work i dont know but i cant download that WinDbg it say that i need to wait till june to upgrade some security setting or something like that...

Comment: You could closely review the Armar_grilla subroutine, since your log is showing the error to possibly be occurring there. You could edit your post to include that code, perhaps someone here could spot something in it, you could add additional logging to the sub to try and track down exactly which line(s) and data could be causing the exception, you could rubber duck walkthrough that code yourself, and so forth.