# COM App calling .NET form calling COM form, works when compiled but not in VB6 IDE

Tags: vb.net, winforms, com, vb6, com-interop

I have a legacy VB6 / COM application that we are migrating all of the code to .NET (VB.NET) via a .NET DLL.  All new form development is being done in the .NET DLL.

We use function pointers to call back to COM functions within .NET form:

1. I create a delegate in .NET
2. Set the delegate to the AddressOf the COM function at runtime (GetDelegateForFunctionPointer)
3. Show the .NET Form
4. Invoke the delegate

COM App --> .NET Form --> COM function

This works fine for functions.  Where this breaks down is when I call a COM function that shows a form.

COM App --> .NET Form --> COM function --> COM Form

The COM function will execute and the form will show, but when executing in the VB6 IDE the COM form's logic does not execute.  The controls are shown, but any click or form_load events are not executed.  This is not an issue when the VB6 application is compiled.

Another issue I've noticed is that the VB6 IDE "freezes" until the .NET form unloads.  I can not stop the debugger, set breakpoints, or interact with IDE's menu.  It is as if the VB6 IDE allows the .NET DLL to take complete control over the thread.  I believe these two issues are related.

EDIT:
The .NET form is modal, which may be the reason for the IDE thread lock.  I'm just wondering if there is a way around it. Also, I've looked at the InteropForms Toolkit.  It does not solve my problem.  Even setting their sample forms to modal causes the same IDE thread lock to occur.

EDIT 2:
My previous edit did allude to another workaround: Make the .NET form show as modeless when the host application is VB6.

```
If InStr(Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName, "vb6", CompareMethod.Text) > 0 Then
    frm.Show()
Else
    frm.ShowDialog()
    frm.Dispose()
End If
```

Comment: if you are migrating all the code to .net, why do you still have COM objects and a VB6 IDE?

Comment: More than 90% of the logic is VB6.  We are focusing on adding critical features with .NET.  A rewrite of the VB6 code will come later.

Comment: Can you show a sample of your code that shows how you invoke the COM function?

Comment: Also, the problem with the IDE "freezing" should really be its own question.

Answer (score 3):

The simple COM App --> .NET Form --> COM function --> COM Form scenario can work using the [InteropForms Toolkit 2.1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3264). Here is some code that does it, without using delegates or `AddressOf`.

First, we have our COM library which I'll call ComLibrary. We have the following code:

**SimpleForm.frm:**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_Load()
    MsgBox "In SimpleForm_Load"
End Sub

Private Sub OkButton_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub TalkButton_Click()
    MsgBox "Hello"
End Sub
```

**SimpleClass.cls:**

```
Option Explicit

Public Function ShowTheDialog() As Long
    Dim f As SimpleForm

    Set f = New SimpleForm

    f.Show vbModal

    ShowTheDialog = 1

End Function
```

Compile this to a .dll so that we can reference it in our .NET library.

Next, we'll create our .NET forms library. I did this using the "VB6 InteropForms Library" project template using the default project name of InteropFormsLibrary1. I added a reference to the ComLibrary project. The form has a single button named "CallComFunction."

**InteropForm1.vb:**

```
Imports Microsoft.InteropFormTools

<InteropForm()> _
Public Class InteropForm1
    Private Sub CallComFunction_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles CallComFunction.Click
        Dim sc As ComLibrary.SimpleClass
        sc = New ComLibrary.SimpleClass

        Dim result As Integer
        result = sc.ShowTheDialog()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Before compiling this, we need to create the InteropForms wrapper classes per the toolkit documentation. Do this by accessing the Tools > Generator InteropForms Wrapper Classes menu.

Finally, we create the VB6 host app.

**Form1.frm:**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub DialogButton_Click()
    Dim f As InteropFormLibrary1.InteropForm1

    Set f = New InteropForm1

    f.Show vbModal

End Sub
```

When I run the host application in the VB6 IDE, I can click the button the VB6 form which then displays the VB.NET form. From there, I click another button which uses an instance of SimpleClass to display SimpleForm. The `MsgBox` statements in the form load event and the button click handlers work. And everything works when compiling the VB6 host app as well.

Comment: That looks like a great alternative.  But what if we can not move the VB6/Com form from the VB6 application to its own com library?  The final vb6 form I am attempting to show in the legacy application has many dependencies.  Moving it outside of the VB6 host app project would be a project in itself.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your VB6 IDE is loading your VB application as an "in-process" COM object, although that does not make much sense to me... However if that is the case,it would mean that you have a single message loop for your application and your debugger, which might explain at least some of these issues. I have not used a VB-classic IDE in too many years, so I do not know how it works. Maybe there is an option there somewhere to load your app in a separated process?

**Update -**
It seems my guess was correct. See this other question and its answers for more information and possible workarounds:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/518217/501196

Comment: This is a good idea, never knew about windbg.  I believe you are correct that they share a single message loop.  This is why I think the two issues are related.